# Remove brackets from selected row sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I remove all brackets and marks using python.
Here's my code in flask-python:

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():  
  username = db.session.query(User.username).order_by(User.username.desc()).limit(1).all()
        return render_template("index.html",user = username)
```

and in my `html` file just

```
{{user}}
```

and the result in browser is like:

```
[('tshibek',)]
```

How can I remove all of this and to only get the nickname `tshibek`.

The second question is I want to have an example of 10 last rows (I know how do that) but what I don't know is how to display this nickname like links to the profile, every nickname to another line like the link to the profile.

```
example:
I have rows nickname:
tshibe,tshibek,wasda,something
and i wanna get in HTML link
localhost//profil/tshibe
localhost//profil/tshibek
localhost//profil/wasda
```

...
I dont know how to start with that, can someone show me a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`scalar`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar) instead of `all`

scalar will extract the first value in the tuple returned

so, `[('tshibek',)]` will be returned as `'tshibek'`.

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():  
  username = db.session.query(User.username).order_by(User.username.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
        return render_template("index.html",user = username)
```

if you have a nicknames in a list of tuples

```
rows = [('tshibe',),('tshibek',),('wasda',),('something')]
```

extract the nicknames using list comprehension

```
nicks = [x[0] for x in rows]
```

This will return a list like this:

```
['tshibe','tshibek','wasda','something']
```

you can prepend the base url to it like this

```
base = 'http://localhost/profil'
urls = ['{}/{}'.format(base, n) for n in nicks]
```

Comment: you have a limit 1 on your query

Comment: i know but i want limit 10, how i said in question